# pdf2image fails in docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, poppler, pdf2image

I have a Python project running in a docker container, but I can't get `convert_from_path` to work (from `pdf2image` library). It works locally on my Windows PC, but not in the linux-based docker container.

The error I get each time is `Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?`

Relevant parts of my code look like this

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import os
from sys import exit

def my_function(file_source_path):
    try:
        pages = convert_from_path(file_source_path, 600, poppler_path=os.environ.get('POPPLER_PATH'))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Fail 1')
        print(e)
    try:
        pages = convert_from_path(file_source_path, 600)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Fail 2')
        print(e)
    try:
        pages = convert_from_path(file_source_path, 600, poppler_path=r'\usr\local\bin')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Fail 3')
        print(e)
        print(os.environ)
        exit('Exiting script')
```

In attempt 1 I try to reference the original file saved on windows. Basically the path refers to `'/code/poppler'` which is a binded mount referring to

```
[snippet from docker-compose.yml]
- type: bind
  source: "C:/Program Files/poppler-0.68.0/bin"
  target: /code/poppler
```

In attempt 2 I just try to leave the path empty. In attempt 3 I tried something I found that worked from some other users locally.

Relevant parts of my Dockerfile look like this

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /code

# install poppler
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install poppler-utils -y

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

Comment: I have not verified this yet, but it is likely that this issue is related to Docker fetching stuff from cache instead of building from scratch. I tried to go around this issue by just using PyMuPDF and got it working only after deleting the full build cache in Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that my Docker image was not refreshing correctly and after nuking the build-cache and trying again the middle option worked combined with the above Dockerfile.

So a combination of `RUN apt-get install poppler-utils -y` in the Dockerfile + not referencing the path in the code `pages = convert_from_path(file_source_path, 600)` will work, as it will find the `PATH` automatically when installing `poppler-utils`.

The binded mount can also be removed from `docker-compose.yml` and from the `.env` file.